# Pointers pointing to Array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have written following code in C++:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
    int a[3]={2,3,1};

    int (*ptr)[3];

    ptr=&a;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cout<<*ptr[i]<<"            "<<ptr[i]<<"            "<<&a[i]<<endl;
    }

}
```

And my output is as follows:

```
2            0x61fe04            0x61fe04

6422020      0x61fe10            0x61fe08

2            0x61fe1c            0x61fe0c
```

I can understand that ptr contains the memory location of the array a as it points to the array.

But the array location(3rd col) and my pointer content (2nd col) is not a match.

and what is *ptr giving me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that pointers aren't arrays and arrays aren't pointers. `int (*ptr)[3];` is a pointer to a `int[3]`. When you advance a pointer via `+1` then it advances by the size of the pointee. `ptr` points to a `int[3]` hence pointer aritmethics advances in steps of `sizeof(int[3])`.

On the other hand `a` when decayed to a pointer to the first element of the array, points to an `int`. When you increment `a` it advances by `sizeof(int)`.

Now you just need to consider that `x[i]` is nothing but `*(x + i)`. Hence `ptr[i]` is out of bounds for any `i != 0`. `ptr` is a pointer to a `int[3]` but it does not point to the first element of an array of `int[3]`.

You get expected output via:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
    int a[3]={2,3,1};

    int (*ptr)[3];

    ptr=&a;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cout<< (*ptr)[i]  << " " << &(*ptr)[i]<<" "<< &a[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/7G93z9jEx):

```
2 0x7fff37933320 0x7fff37933320
3 0x7fff37933324 0x7fff37933324
1 0x7fff37933328 0x7fff37933328
```

Answer (score 1):

Add **parentheses** when accessing to your pointer. `*` has higher priority than `[]`, so you get incorrect results.

```
int main()
{
    int a[3]={2,3,1};

    int (*ptr)[3];

    ptr=&a;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        std::cout<<(*ptr)[i]<<"            "<<&(*ptr)[i]<<"            "<<&a[i]<<std::endl;
    }
}
```